# Как мне сделать ввод строки и числа через запятую?

Tags: c#

мне нужно принимать не отдельно текст и число, а одной строкой через запятую, например: "Введите число и текст: 1,Ouu", "Введите число и текст: 2, May".

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
    string text1 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Введите число: ");
    int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Введите текст: ");
    string text2 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Введите число: ");
    int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        var dividesBy3 = i % number1 == 0;
        var dividesBy5 = i % number2 == 0;
    
        if (dividesBy3 && dividesBy5)
            Console.WriteLine(text1 + text2);
        else if (dividesBy3)
            Console.WriteLine(text1);
        else if (dividesBy5)
            Console.WriteLine(text2);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
Console.Write("Введите число и текст через запятую: ");
string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
int number = int.Parse(tokens[0]);
string text = tokens[1].Trim(); // тримминг пробела, если введено через запятую и пробел
```

Начинайте учиться писать код самостоятельно. Чем дальше - тем сложнее будет.